# Are there practical limits to the number of cores accessing the same memory?

Tags: performance, hardware, cpu, multicore

Will the current trend of adding cores to computers continue?  Or is there some theoretical or practical limit to the number of cores that can be served by one set of memory?

Put another way:  is the high powered desktop computer of the future apt to have 1024 cores using one set of memory, or is it apt to have 32 sets of memory, each accessed by 32 cores?

Or still another way:  I have a multi-threaded program that runs well on a 4-core machine, using a significant amount of the total CPU.  As this program grows in size and does more work, can I be reasonably confident more powerful machines will be available to run it?  *Or* should I be thinking seriously about running multiple sessions on multiple machines (or at any rate multiple sets of memory) to get the work done?

In other words, is a purely multithreaded approach to design going to leave me in a dead end?  (As using a single threaded approach and depending on continued improvements in CPU speed years back would have done?)  The program is unlikely to be run on a machine costing more than, say $3,000.  If that machine cannot do the work, the work won't get done.  But if that $3,000 machine is actually a network of 32 independent computers (though they may share the same cooling fan) and I've continued my massively multithreaded approach, the machine will be able to do the work, but the program won't, and I'm going to be in an awkward spot.

Distributed processing looks like a bigger pain than multithreading was, but if that might be in my future, I'd like some warning.

Comment: A cpu core doesn't access memory directly.  On an upscale Xeon type core there are three levels of cache in between.  But sure, memory bus bandwidth is often a practical bottleneck, it is *much* slower than the cpu and you pay big bucks to get a faster bus.  At least another order of magnitude slower still if you network machines.  It entirely depends on your code how well the caches will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the current trend of adding cores to computers continue?

Yes, the GHz race is over. It's not practical to ramp the speed any more on the current technology. Physics has gotten in the way. There may be a dramatic shift in the technology of fabricating chips that allows us to get round this, but it's not obviously 'just around the corner'.

If we can't have faster cores, the only way to get more power is to have more cores.

> Or is there some theoretical or practical limit to the number of cores that can be served by one set of memory?

Absolutely there's a limit. In a shared memory system the memory is a shared resource and has a limited amount of bandwidth.

```
Max processes = (Memory Bandwidth) / (Bandwidth required per process)
```

Now - that 'Bandwidth per process' figure will be reduced by caches, but caches become less efficient if they have to be coherent with one another because everyone is accessing the same area of memory. (You can't cache a memory write if another CPU may need what you've written)

When you start talking about huge systems, shared resources like this become the main problem. It might be memory bandwidth, CPU cycles, hard drive access, network bandwidth. It comes down to how the system as a whole is structured.

---

You seem to be really asking for a vision of the future so you can prepare. Here's my take.

I think we're going to see a change in the way software developers see parallelism in their programs. At the moment, I would say that a lot of software developers see the only way of using multiple threads is to have lots of them doing the same thing. The trouble is they're all contesting for the same resources. This then means lots of locking needs to be introduced, which causes performance issues, and subtle bugs which are infuriating and time consuming to solve.

This isn't sustainable.

Manufacturing worked out at the beginning of the 20th Century, the fastest way to build lots of cars wasn't to have lots of people working on one car, and then, when that one's done, move them all on to the next car. It was to split the process of building the car down into lots of small jobs, with the output of one job feeding the next. They called it assembly lines. In hardware design it's called pipe-lining, and I'll think we'll see software designs move to it more and more, as it minimizes the problem of shared resources.

Sure - There's still a shared resource on the output of one stage and the input of the next, but this is only between two threads/processes and is much easier to handle. Standard methods can also be adopted on how these interfaces are made, and message queueing libraries seem to be making big strides here.

There's not one solution for all problems though. This type of pipe-line works great for high throughput applications that can absorb some latency. If you can't live with the latency, you have no option but to go the 'many workers on a single task' route. Those are the ones you ideally want to be throwing at SIMD machines/Array processors like GPUs, but it only really excels with a certain type of problem. Those problems are ones where there's lots of data to process in the same way, and there's very little or no dependency between data items.

Having a good grasp of message queuing techniques and similar for pipelined systems, and utilising fine grained parallelism on GPUs through libraries such as OpenCL, will give you insight at both ends of the spectrum.

Comment: Interesting answer.  I particularly like the problem of software getting lost in locks and bugs well before hardware limits are reached.

Comment: Pipe-lining seems to be the key concept here.  I am looking at running on a $3000 desktop five to ten years from now with software that needs to use about 90% of the machine's capacity.  The question then is do I use a message queue that works within a session?  This would be a thread-safe queue structure, or "collection".  It would require all the machine's cores to use the same memory.  Or do I use sockets?  This would work if the desktop was actually a self-contained computer network.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  Multi-threaded code may run on clustered machines, so this issue *may* not be as critical as I thought.

I was carefully checking out the Java Memory Model in the JLS, chapter 17, and found it does *not* mirror the typical register-cache-main memory model of most computers.  There were opportunities there for a multi-memory machine to cleanly shift data from one memory to another (and from one thread running on one machine to another running on a different one).  So I started searching for JVMs that would run across multiple machines.  I found several old references--the idea has been out there, but not followed through.  However, one company, Terracotta, seems to have something, if I'm reading their PR right.

At any rate, it rather seems that when PC's typically contain several clustered machines, there's likely to be a multi-machine JVM for them.

I could find nothing outside the Java world, but Microsoft's CLR ought to provide the same opportunities.  C and C++ and all the other .exe languages might be more difficult.  However, Terracotta's websites talk more about linking JVM's rather than one JVM on multiple machines, so their tricks might work for executable langauges also (and maybe the CLR, if needed).